# This sender failed our fraud detection checks and may not be who they appear to be. Learn about spoofing

Tags: php, email, dns, spoofing

We are sending emails from domain and getting below warning in email body kindly let me know why this showing me?

"This sender failed our fraud detection checks and may not be who they appear to be. Learn about spoofing."

Help me to fixing this issue.

Comment: Do you have SPF and DKIM set up correctly for your domain, with appropriate SPF settings for the server being used to send the email?